# Highlight custom language on MediaWiki page

Tags: syntax-highlighting, mediawiki-extensions, pygments, pygmentize

My goal is add syntax highlighting for a custom language on my wiki page. In order to do that, I installed Pygments and added my own lexer file (mylexer.py). Since I don't want to pull request the lexer and wait for it to be merged, how do I edit the create_pygmentize_script (linked below) so it uses the locally installed Pygments to create the bundle?

script: https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-extensions-SyntaxHighlight_GeSHi/blob/master/pygments/create_pygmentize_bundle

Pygments Installation Location on local machine: `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pygments`

I have been stuck with it for a while now. Any help would be appreciated.